# java.nio.file implementation for AWS

Tags: java, amazon-s3, java.nio.file, s3fs-nio

Is there any official `java.nio.file` implementation for `AWS`?

I found one for `GoogleCloudStorage` [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/tree/master/google-cloud-contrib/google-cloud-nio), and need similar for `AWS` and `Azure`.

Comment: There seems not to be an offical `java.nio.file` implementation for Azure. What you want to do using a cloud implementation for Java NIO?

Comment: I need this as an abstraction for different types of storages.

Comment: I got it, but there is nothing. The only way is defining your own apis to implement the wrapper for the different types of storage.

Comment: I'm also looking to abstract away non-standard AWS S3 APIs and somehow hide it behind "volume services" or Java NIO classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## General

For anyone interested, the [Upplication/Amazon-S3-FileSystem-NIO2](https://github.com/Upplication/Amazon-S3-FileSystem-NIO2) was abandoned a very long time ago. Pull requests and fixes are no longer accepted. Many developers forked it and made their fixes for their own purposes and then those forks died as well.

We decided to make a new new spin-off project -- not as a fork, but as a new project called [s3fs-nio](https://github.com/carlspring/s3fs-nio) that is based on [Upplication/Amazon-S3-FileSystem-NIO2](https://github.com/Upplication/Amazon-S3-FileSystem-NIO2)'s `master`. You can find out more about the history and reasoning [here](https://s3fs-nio.carlspring.org/history/). We have tried to collect some of the more important fixes from forks and have added them to our project (with the authors' permissions).

Our spin-off uses AWS SDK for Java version 2.x and is under an Apache 2.0 license.

The documentation for configuring things can be found [here](https://s3fs-nio.carlspring.org/).

Code examples are located [here](https://s3fs-nio.carlspring.org/reference/examples/basic-example/).

We've now cut a release for `org.carlspring.cloud.aws:s3fs-nio:1.0.0` and this is available via Maven Central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/). Here are our [Release Notes](https://github.com/carlspring/s3fs-nio/releases/tag/v1.0.0).

We are also working on improving our [documentation](https://s3fs-nio.carlspring.org/) and contributions would be highly appreciated.

We would like to welcome you to test and report back any findings!

For those of you interested in contributing, there is plenty yet to be done and we'd be more than happy to have you aboard!

## Basic Example

Here's a basic configuration:

- Add the respective dependency (you can check the available versions [here](https://github.com/carlspring/s3fs-nio/releases)):

  - For Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.carlspring.cloud.aws</groupId>
    <artifactId>s3fs-nio</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

- For Gradle:

```
implementation 'org.carlspring.cloud.aws:s3fs-nio:1.0.0'
```

- Use a Service Locator and an `amazon.properties` file
  In your `src/main/resources/amazon.properties`, add the following settings:

```
s3fs.access.key=access-key
s3fs.secret.key=secret-key
```

Use the following code to create the FileSystem and set it to a specific end-point:

```
FileSystems.newFileSystem(URI.create("s3:///"),
                          new HashMap<>(),
                          Thread.currentThread()
                                .getContextClassLoader());
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try using [Amazon AWS S3 FileSystem Provider JSR-203 for Java 7 (NIO2)](https://github.com/Upplication/Amazon-S3-FileSystem-NIO2)

**Download from Maven Central**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.upplication</groupId>
    <artifactId>s3fs</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

add to your META-INF/services/java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider (create if not exists yet) a new line like this: com.upplication.s3fs.S3FileSystemProvider.

**Use this code to create the fileSystem and set to a concrete endpoint.**

```
FileSystems.newFileSystem("s3:///", new HashMap<String,Object>(), Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
```

**How to use in Apache MINA**

```
public FileSystemFactory createFileSystemFactory(String bucketName) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
    FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystems.newFileSystem(new URI("s3:///"), env, Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
    String bucketPath = fileSystem.getPath("/" + bucketName);

    return new VirtualFileSystemFactory(bucketPath);
}
```

**How to use in Spring**

Add to classpath and configure:

```
@Configuration
public class AwsConfig {

    @Value("${upplication.aws.accessKey}")
    private String accessKey;

    @Value("${upplication.aws.secretKey}")
    private String secretKey;

    @Bean
    public FileSystem s3FileSystem() throws IOException {
        Map<String, String> env = new HashMap<>();
        env.put(com.upplication.s3fs.AmazonS3Factory.ACCESS_KEY, accessKey);
        env.put(com.upplication.s3fs.AmazonS3Factory.SECRET_KEY, secretKey);

        return FileSystems.newFileSystem(URI.create("s3:///"), env, Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
    }
}
```

**Inject in any spring component:**

```
@Autowired
private FileSystem s3FileSystem;
```

Comment: This library is no longer maintained. We have made a spin-off project inspired by it and based on its original code base. Please, see my answer below for more details.

Answer (score 3):

An implementation of the `FileSystemProvider` SPI that uses asynchronous read-ahead buffering is available [from github](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-java-nio-spi-for-s3) and [from Maven Central](https://central.sonatype.dev/artifact/software.amazon.nio.s3/aws-java-nio-spi-for-s3/1.1.1). This library supports reads and writes.

You can include it in a Maven project using:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>software.amazon.nio.s3</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-nio-spi-for-s3</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Or you can just place the JAR file on your classpath and the JVM will route all URIs with a scheme of `s3` to this provider.

Answer (score 1):

According to a [comment](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/issues/1388#issuecomment-1560274386) on [S3: provide java.nio.FileSystem implementation #1388](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/issues/1388), someone just released v1.0.0 (now v1.0.1) of S3FS NIO at [carlspring /
s3fs-nio](https://github.com/carlspring/s3fs-nio) on GitHub. I haven't had a chance to try it out. If anyone does, please leave your experience here in the comments.